# Reverse Assets fixedOrder

Tags: assets, ordering

Is there a way to reverse the Assets field keeping the fixed order? I've tried a couple of things:

```
myAssetsField.order('fixedOrder desc') //breaks
myAssetsField.order('id desc') // wrong, since they're not sorted by id
myAssetsField.reverse() // does nothing
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [twig's reverse filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/reverse.html).

```
{% for asset in entry.assetsField|reverse %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the order parameter to `'sortOrder desc'`:

```
{% set assets = myAssetsField.order('sortOrder desc') %}
```

Comment: The value isn't in the [list of possible values](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#order) in the Craft docs, but I will make P&T aware of this.

Comment: Ah. That's the sort parameter I was looking for. Marked Douglas' answer as accepted just because he was 3 minutes earlier, and both answers work. (And he has less rep than you)